# mysql replication error:Slave I/O: error connecting to master

Tags: mysql, replication, high-availability

I used keepalived+proxy+mysql.
Master:192.168.10.1
Slave:192.168.10.2
Master-VIP:192.168.10.100
When I use `CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='192.168.10.1'...`, replication is OK, when I use `CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='192.168.10.100'...`, Slave I/O can't connect to master, and I got error like this:

> 150522 15:21:50 [ERROR] Slave I/O: error connecting to master
>   'repl@192.168.10.100:3307' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400,
>   Error_code: 2003 
> 150522 15:21:50 [Note] Slave SQL thread initialized,
>   starting replication in log 'mysql-bin.000001' at position 107, relay
>   log './mmm-relay-bin.000001' position: 4

In slave, I use `mysql -urepl -pslavepass -h192.168.10.100 -P3307`, I can login the db, why does Slave I/O can't connect to master?

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue when replicating from RDS to a standalone instance. Were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to unblock port 3306 on the master server.
http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/opening-ports-in-your-firewall/

Answer (score 0):

You may need to tune SELinux for non-standard ports like 3307. At first check allowed ports (install `policycoreutils-python` package if `semanage` command is not found):

```
# semanage port -l | grep 3306
mysqld_port_t                  tcp      1186, 3306
```

There's no 3307 port there. Add it:

```
# semanage port -a -t mysqld_port_t -p tcp 3307
# semanage port -l | grep 3306
mysqld_port_t                  tcp      3307, 1186, 3306
```

Source: http://dossy.org/2011/11/mysql-replication-connection-error-on-non-standard-ports/